# jQuery $.get() not succeeding with XML file

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an xml file called `markers.xml` which is formatted like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<marker>
    <name></name>
    <fulladdress></fulladdress>
    <lat></lat>
    <lng></lng>
    <isSiteLocation></isSiteLocation>
</marker>
```

My jQuery function trying to use the file looks like this

```
MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {  
    $.get(filename,{}, function(xml) {    
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function() {      
            var name = $(this).find('name').text();      
            var address = $(this).find('address').text();            

            // create a new LatLng point for the marker      
            var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();      
            var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
            var isSiteLocation = $(this).find('isSiteLocation').text();
            var markerIcon = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/" + (isSiteLocation) ? "blue-dot.png" : "red-dot.png";

            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));            

            // extend the bounds to include the new point      
            MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);      

            // add the marker itself      
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({        
                position: point,        
                map: MYMAP.map,
                icon: markerIcon      
            });      

            // create the tooltip and its text      
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();      
            var html='<b>'+name+'</b><br />'+address;      

            // add a listener to open the tooltip when a user clicks on one of the markers      
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {        
                infoWindow.setContent(html);        
                infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);      
            });    
        });        

        // Fit the map around the markers we added:    
        MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);  
    }, "xml");
}
```

and it is called by a onclick event which tells it the xml file name here

```
$("#showmarkers").click(function(e) {    
    MYMAP.placeMarkers('markers.xml');  
});
```

My problem is that when the `MYMAP.placeMarkers` function is called the javascript doesn't ever enter the success function. I followed it using the javascript debugger and it looked like my file name was being rejected. The javascript, html and xml files are in the same directory on my hosted website [here](http://thefactory.comeze.com/Add%20Markers.html).

I am attempting to follow a tutorial [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/google-maps-api-jquery/) which goes through the process of populating a google map with markers using data extracted from a saved xml file.

Before I asked this question I've been doing research and I found a question on here that was very similar to mine [jQuery is not reading xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673885/jquery-is-not-reading-xml-file)

I followed the accepted answer and put the braces before my function and I put "xml" right before the closing parentheses but nothing changed. The console gives me no error and I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: [Your XML file has an error](http://thefactory.comeze.com/markers.xml).

Comment: You need a single top-level element. You have three.